# Show memory usage of a coldfusion page

Tags: coldfusion

Coldfusion has a server monitor that will show "Requests by memory usage". Is there a way to show a request size of a page on the page itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "request size of a page"?

Comment: Memory consumed during execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a before and after value and subtract the two.  You can find the memory being used like this:

```
runtime = CreateObject("java","java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime();
totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory() / 1024 / 1024;//currently in use
```